# How can I get a list of the best answers from a particular site?

Tags: accepted-answer, discussion, top-answers

I'd like to browse through the best answers from a site, for example from ServerFault.

I'm sure they would contain great information but I can't find a way to access just the top answers (regardless of the question)

Comment: Keep in mind that there isn't necessarily a direct correlation between "top-voted" answers and "best" answers.  (Depending on how one subjectively defines "best")  A lot of answers have tons of up-votes because they've been around for years and have been stumbled across via Google many times.  A quick little answer (or several of the same quick little answer) on a commonly-viewed question will dramatically out-rank a fantastic answer on a less popular question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want just the answers, you can set up a search using `is:answer`:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aanswer

This will give you all answers on the site, sorted in the descending order by votes. So, the top-voted (and theoretically "best") answers will be shown first regardless of the question.

See more search options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search). This will work on any site, just replace "stackoverflow.com" with the relevant domain.

Comment: Wow I did not know this... thanks for the link for search options.

Answer (score -1):

Go to any SE website. Press the Questions tab, then press the votes tab. This shows a list of all questions with the highest amount of votes (and with this comes, in most cases, the best answers). As shown below:

**Step 1**
[image]

---

**Step 2**
[image]

Comment: I want the top rated Answers not the top rated Questions

Comment: @ckliborn and I explained that you could find some of the best rated answers in the best rated questions in my answer...

Comment: +1 for freehand circles

Comment: -1 For an irrelevant answer...

Comment: @JNK'sMetAccount it was not irrelevant, it was a method of finding out what the asker wanted. My method wasn't as efficient as the... other answer but it still works somewhat

Comment: There is kind of sort of a link between high voted questions and high voted answers, but not strong enough to validate checking all the high-voted questions for high-voted answers.  The highest-voted answer is in the 8th highest question, and the #3 answer is on a question that's not even in the top 100....